# Magento 2 : How to check customer first order?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer

How to check if customer with first order or not for login and guest users?
What is the proper way to check if customer is first time placed an order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into core modules, found solutions in magento 2:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function getFirstOrder($emailId){
        $emailId = 'testtest@testtests.com';

        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',array('eq'=>$emailId))->getFirstItem();

        if($order->getCustomerEmail()){
            echo 'second time order';
        }
        else{
            echo 'first time order';
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you check this? i want to do this in new grid is that possible?